# web data graph google trends ui style

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, gwt, user-interface

I would like to create a site that would display csv data.
I'd really like it to look like google trends/finance.
Optional: Allow users to tag peaks in the data and describe what they are

How would you go about implementing this?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) ?

Here is the [playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization) to check how it would look like.

Hope this helps!